# confused with dbms_xplan.display()

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I'm trying like this:

```
create table btree_unique(num number,name varchar2(15));
```

Inserted 1000000 rows in the table(all are unique)

```
analyze table btree_unique compute statistics;
```

Now I'm trying to search for the number 987653

Explain plan looks like this

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from index_btree_unique where num=987653;
```

Explained.

```
SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 453130233

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------

| Id  | Operation         | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Ti
me     |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                    |     1 |    11 |   697   (3)| 00
:00:09 |

|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| INDEX_BTREE_UNIQUE |     1 |    11 |   697   (3)| 00
:00:09 |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
Create unique index i on btree_unique(num);

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 230012590

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----

| Id  | Operation                   | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time
   |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |      |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:
01 |

|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SS   |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:
01 |

|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I1   |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:
01 |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("NUM"=987653)
```

Oracle will do sequential search if we have not created any index on the column. In the first step without creating index I had searched for num 987653.

In the explain plan it was showing as "FUll TABLE SCAN" but number of rows scanned only 1 it should show 1000000 right? . After creating index there was decrease in CPU usage and TIME but rows scanned were same in both the cases.

Can anyone please explain the rows part in the explain plan?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confused with dbms\_xplan.display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091137/confused-with-dbms-xplan-display)

Comment: It's better to modify your old question instead of asking a new one.  If previous answers aren't helpful you can add comments to request changes or more information.

Answer (score 3):

[As the documentation explains](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/ex_plan.htm) the ROWS values it is the estimated number of rows the step is estimated to access (i.e. the cardinality), not the number of rows it will have to examine. The optimiser uses the cardinality to determine the best join and filter order, and whether it would be beneficial to use an index (if one exists).

If you execute the actual query, not just explain the plan for it, you can see the execution statistics which will show the number of logical and physical buffer gets.